# iOS MDM client app sending token to app server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I need some information about sending the token from `iOS` to the server. I know that when developing an app, `NSURL` can be used to specify remote server location. But, in the case of `MDM` in `iOS`, the MDM client is an in-built service. So, how do I send the device token to the MDM server? Can coding be done on built-in MDM client? How did the `iOS` MDM client knows to which server the token is to be sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is contained in the MDM profile. There will be a MDM Server URL and Checkin URL, which is where the device sends the tokens to.